# phpstan: Template type only for return type

Tags: php, phpstan

I think I am misunderstanding something about phpstan.

I have the following method in my interface:

```php
    /**
     * @phpstan-template T of Searchable
     *
     * @param string                $indexName
     * @param ?array<string, mixed> $config
     *
     * @phpstan-return IndexResponse<T>
     *
     * @throws SearchEngineException
     */
    public function createIndex(string $indexName, ?array $config): IndexResponse;
```

But I get following notice from phpstan:
`phpstan: Template type T of method App\Service\Common\Search\SearchEngine::createIndex() is not referenced in a parameter.`

Okay...T is not in any parameter definition. But why is that necessary?
I actually only wanted it for the return type definition.
I don't understand why this is not "enough"?

Comment: I think it's more to let you know that when you call `createIndex('a', [])` it can't really know what the return type will be because it can't use the parameters to infer what T will be. It's a notice probably to draw this to your attention

Comment: Ahhhh, that might be! I am only beginning to wrap my head around it so i probably have misconceptions left. I initially thought it might be possible to specify the exact type on method call for a method with generic return type and with that, narrow down type-info so client-code can be checked more strictly. But it begins to feel weird to me if the type-info would have to come from the caller in my example so it would require some annotation within method or function scope to set T to something "real".

I think I am basically encountering this problem due to an architectural flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature:

```php
    /**
     * @phpstan-template T of Searchable
     *
     * @param string                $indexName
     * @param ?array<string, mixed> $config
     *
     * @phpstan-return IndexResponse<T>
     *
     * @throws SearchEngineException
     */
```

is equivalent to:

```php
    /**
     * @param string                $indexName
     * @param ?array<string, mixed> $config
     *
     * @phpstan-return IndexResponse<Searchable>
     *
     * @throws SearchEngineException
     */
```

Because without referencing `T` in a parameter type, there's no way for a caller to influence what `T` is.

Please refer to these article to learn about basics of generics in PHPDocs, and to learn some example of most common problems solved by generics in PHPDocs:

- https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-in-php-using-phpdocs
- https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-by-examples